# Send join table column id using jbuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, join, has-many-through, jbuilder

I have a `has_many :through` join table between games and servers called `games_servers` and I'm trying to send an array of `id` for the `servers` for a `game` as follows:

```
json.servers do
  json.array!(game.servers {|g| g.id})
end
```

But it sends the whole `server` record rather than just the `id`. I tried the following too:

```
json.servers do
  json.array!(game.servers {|g| json.(g, :id)})
end
```

But even this sends the whole `server` record. Is there a way for me to just send the `id` of the `server` records in an array?

I can do `json.array!(game.servers.pluck(:server_id))` to get only the `id` in an array but this leads to the `N+1` query issue

Answer (score 0):

You can try following to get `ids` of `server`

```
game.server_ids
```

this will be shortest code to get ids of associated model.

Hope this will work for you..